# PHP Get dates for two specific weekdays

Tags: php, datetime

So i have this PHP code:

```
$date = new DateTime('1990-01 Wednesday');
$thisMonth = $date->format('Y');

while ($date->format('Y') === $thisMonth) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), "<br>";
    $date->modify('next Wednesday');
}
```

my goal is that I get all wednesdays and saturdays from X (e.g: 1990) till today.

But i have some problems and maybe you can help me a little !

Thanks !

Comment: A side note: I highly recommend using the Carbon library when working with dates in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a clear "start" and "end" date then increment 1 day at a time. On each iteration check the day of the week and output if it satisfies your condition.

```
$start = new DateTime('1990-01 Wednesday');
$end = new DateTime('now');

while($start<$end){
    $dayOfWeek = $start->format('D');
    if($dayOfWeek==="Wed" || $dayOfWeek==="Sat"){
        echo $start->format('Y-m-d'),"<br>";
    }
    $start->modify('+1 day');
}
```